# How do I reverse the animation of a drawing in P5JS (more details in post)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Source Code: https://editor.p5js.org/theruantan/sketches/aFXKo_s86

Basically I'm trying to do a [pseudo generative poster that swaps between 3 artworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZknY.gif)  that I have predesigned. The idea is to make load one artpiece, wait a few seconds then reverse (essentially wipe it away) the drawing to a blank canvas then load the next and repeat endlessly.

I'm just trying to recreate the reversal animation that I saw here: https://www.reddit.com/r/generative/comments/q6krwj/lines_p5js/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic way to rewind an animation like this. You could do something very memory intensive such as saving every frame of the animation as an image and then playing the whole thing backward, but this would use a lot of memory. Instead you can just reverse the logic that animates the various shapes:

```js
let masks = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // Create Masks for Artwork Background
let switches = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // To switch on each background line

let mainMask = 400; // Create Main mask to reveal artwork

let cityActiveState = 0; // To determine if the current artwork is active or erased -- either 0 or 1.

let sunXPos = 0; // To Move the sun around
let sunYPos = -100;

let rods = -100; // Animate lightning rods for city

function setup() {
  createCanvas(180, 216);
  frameRate(60);

  console.log(`${switches.length} Swithces`);
  console.log(`${masks.length} Masks`);
}

function draw() {
  let beige = color(251, 242, 224);
  let red = color(245, 105, 96);
  let blue = color(96, 152, 190);
  let green = color(124, 167, 122);
  let headBlack = color(60, 60, 59);
  let textBlack = color(112, 111, 111);

  background(beige);

  push();
  scale(0.2);
  translate(50, 240);
  citySkyline(red, beige);
  pop();
}

function citySkyline(color1, color2) {
  // Animate artwork
  if (cityActiveState == 0) {
    sunXPos = 650;
    if (!switches[0]) {
      switches[0] = 1;
    }
    let animating = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < switches.length; i++) {
      if (switches[i] == 1) {
        if (masks[i] < 800) {
          masks[i] += 20;
          animating = true;
        }
        if (masks[i] >= 300) {
          if (i + 1 < switches.length) {
            switches[i + 1] = 1;
          }

          if (i == 12) {
            // Only increase these once masks[12] reaches 300
            if (mainMask < 1500) {
              mainMask += 10;
              animating = true;
            }

            if (rods < 371) {
              rods += 15;
              animating = true;
            }

            if (sunYPos < 140) {
              sunYPos += 7.5;
              animating = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (!animating) {
      console.log("city is now active");
      cityActiveState = 1;
    }
  } else if (cityActiveState == 1) {
    // Reverse animation
    let animating = false;
    if (mainMask > 400 || rods > -100 || sunYPos > -100) {
      animating = true;
      if (mainMask > 400) {
        mainMask -= 10;
      }

      if (rods > -100) {
        rods -= 15;
      }

      if (sunYPos > -100) {
        sunYPos -= 7.5;
      }
    } else {
      if (switches[switches.length - 1]) {
        switches[switches.length - 1] = 0;
      }
      for (let i = switches.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (switches[i] == 0) {
          if (masks[i] > 0) {
            masks[i] -= 20;
            animating = true;
          }
          if (masks[i] <= 300) {
            // Begin reversing the next bar
            switches[i - 1] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (!animating) {
      console.log("city is now inactive");
      cityActiveState = 0;
    }
  }

  // draw actual artwork
  push();
  noStroke();
  fill(color1);
  translate(225, 285);
  rect(50, 0, 250, 20);
  rect(0, 55, 350, 10);
  rect(0, 95, 350, 10);
  rect(0, 135, 350, 50);
  rect(0, 215, 350, 30);
  rect(0, 275, 350, 10);
  rect(0, 315, 350, 40);
  rect(0, 385, 350, 60);
  rect(0, 475, 350, 40);
  pop();

  // reveal artwork
  push();
  noStroke();
  fill(color2);
  rectMode(RADIUS);
  rect(mainMask, 400, 400, 400);
  pop();

  push();
  noStroke();
  fill(color1);
  rect(0, 0, masks[0], 100);
  rect(0, 110, masks[1], 70);
  rect(0, 190, masks[2], 50);
  rect(0, 250, masks[3], 35);
  rect(0, 315, masks[4], 25);
  rect(0, 370, masks[5], 10);
  rect(0, 410, masks[6], 10);
  rect(0, 490, masks[7], 10);
  rect(0, 550, masks[8], 10);
  rect(0, 590, masks[9], 10);
  rect(0, 660, masks[10], 10);
  rect(0, 750, masks[11], 10);
  pop();

  // draw lighting rods
  push();
  noStroke();
  fill(color2);
  translate(0, 100);
  rect(rods + 30, 0, 20, 140);
  translate(0, 40);
  rect(rods, 0, 10, 100);
  pop();

  // draw sun
  push();
  noStroke();
  fill(color2);
  circle(sunXPos, sunYPos, 143);
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I stripped down the code and had to fiddle with a few bugs to make this work. Hopefully the basic concept is clear.

Comment: Thanks, this made my first two scenes work perfectly. I actually have one more question, cause when I tried implementing this to the last beach scene, the masks don't actually get reversed. Line 127 to reverse the mask totally doesn't get called at all, which I can't figure out why. When I print the value of the mask, it says it's 780 and doesn't subtract any further to hit the required 300 in the parameter. 

Here is the link: https://editor.p5js.org/theruantan/sketches/8g583LF8j

Comment: I believe you were just using the wrong variable name on line 110. You had `animating = true;` where you should have `beachAnimate = true;`